# How to box int (enum) to object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to cast an int to an object, in Objective-C I could do the following

```
[row.cellConfig setObject:@(UITextFieldViewModeAlways) forKey:@"textField.rightViewMode"];
```

What would be the Swift equivalent?

Comment: That isn't casting, it's boxing into an `NSNumber`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift equivalent of `UITextFieldViewModeAlways` is
`UITextFieldViewMode.Always`, which is an enumeration value:

```
enum UITextFieldViewMode : Int {
    case Never
    case WhileEditing
    case UnlessEditing
    case Always
}
```

You get its underlying integer value with `.rawValue`. 
Integers are automatically "bridged" to `NSNumber` when passed
to functions taking Objective-C parameters (and Swift strings
bridged to `NSString`).

So this should work:

```
row.cellConfig.setObject(UITextFieldViewMode.Always.rawValue,
                forKey: "textField.rightViewMode")
```

For more information, see [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
row.cellConfig.setObject(NSNumber(UITextFieldViewModeAlways), forKey:"textField.rightViewMode")
```

Comment: Sorry, use `NSNumber(int: UITextFieldViewModeAlways)`

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a NSNumber object for that int.

```
NSNumber *intObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:num];
```

Comment: that's objective-c mate, i've asked for Swift :)

Comment: var newNumber : NSNumber = NSNumber(int: num)